# Behavior of the typeof keyword

Tags: javascript, typeof

Learning about the `typeof` keyword and need some clarification:

While troubleshooting I outputted this code to the console:

```
console.log(typeof object.prop[someNum - 1]);
```

(in this case `sumNum === 0`)

The console printed out `undefined` which is what I expected because the index position `[someNum - 1]` in the `prop[]` array doesn't exist (so I thought). 
However when I do something like this:

```
if(typeof object.prop[someNum - 1])
    //some code
 else
    //other code
```

It evaluates as true and runs `//some code` but when I do this:

```
if(object.prop[someNum - 1])
    //some code
 else
    //other code
```

It evaluates as false and runs `//other code`.

I was under the impression that `undefined` is considered a `falsy value`and would evaluate false in an `if statement`. Why is the `if(typeof object.prop[someNum - 1])` statement evaluating as as true? Also can someone point me in the right direction as to where I can learn more about negative indexing arrays in `js`? Are they handled the same across multiple languages like `c#, c++, java, & php`. I thought when evaluating a negative `array` index number it would be `underfined` or throw an error.

Comment: `undefined` is not the same as `"undefined"`.

Comment: Since you're learning the `typeof` keyword, here's the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) on it (just in case).

Comment: If you're checking for the existence of the property, you don't really need `typeof`. You can do `(someNum-1) in object.prop` or if you're worried about inherited properties, `object.prop.hasOwnProperty(someNum-1)`. Using `typeof` won't differentiate between the property existing with the `undefined` value, and the property not existing.

Comment: @squint I see. can you provide a jsfidle or short code snippet? not sure if the way you wrote it `(someNum - 1)` is the index of the array

Answer (score 5):

`typeof` always returns a string.

Therefore, you're writing `if ("undefined")`.

Since non-empty strings are truthy, that if will run.

Answer (score 1):

As SLaks says, you're evaluating if the string "undefined" is truthy, which it is.

If you want to see if an object has a property called "someNum - 1" then you can use the *in* operator:

```
if ((someNum - 1) in object.prop)
```

which will return true if *object.prop* has such a property anywhere on itself or its `[[Prototype]]` chain, or:

```
if (object.prop.hasOwnProperty(someNum - 1))
```

to test for the property directly on the object.

Comment: have an array of objects so `(someNum - 1) was the array index. with that said what is `.prop` in `object.prop` referring to?

Comment: It's using the [*in*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator to test if a property exists. The brackets around `(sumNum - 1)` mean "evaluate this expression first, then use the result in the outer expression". ;-)

Comment: gotcha. Thanks alot. you've been a big help

Comment: It's worth noting any properties set to `undefined` will be included by the `in` operator.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have pointed out, `typeof` returns a string, and it will always be truthy because it never returns an empty string. If you want to test if the type is `undefined`, you need to compare the string.

```
if (typeof object.prop[someNum - 1] == "undefined") {
    // some code
} else {
    // some code
}
```

You could also just test whether the value is `undefined`:

```
if (object.prop[someNum - 1] === undefined) {
    // some code
} else { 
    // some code
}
```

Make sure you use `===` rather than `==`, so it won't report a match if `object[someNum - 1]` is `null`.