# if(false) vs if(undefined) in conditional statement

Tags: javascript

I will like to know which will be more appropriate to use while writing a conditional statement in javascript

```
if(false){}
```

or

```
if(undefined){}
```

Also I know `if(undefined)` will be converted to false is javascript

**Background**

I have a function & an object like this

```
var obj ={}
var someFunc = function(a){
     obj = {
         key1:true,
         key2:a, // i will like to have it as a?true:false
         key3: !a
    }
```

I am calling the function like this

```
someFunc(true);
```

if I call like this `someFunc()` , without passing the argument , then `key2` will be undefined.

later I want to use this key in conditional statement

```
if(obj.key2){

}
```

As mentioned I know if `obj.key2` is undefined, it will be coerced as `if(false)`.

Comment: None. Since, the `if` block will not execute if the value is falsey.

Comment: I know the statement inside if block wont be executed if it is falsy ,  but my question is which one is more appropriate to check the falsy condition

Comment: `key2 in obj` will make more sense here.

Comment: Checking with `false` should take lesser time than coercing `undefined` to `Boolean` and then doing the check. Although I doubt if the effect would be visible, but I think `false` is better.

Comment: If they'er both checking the 'falsey' then why does it matter which one is more appropriate? It only matters if you're doing strict comparison.

Comment: Semantically, I think `undefined` isn't "false" so much as it is "not true". Anyway, in the context of your object, "more appropriate" is a matter of opinion. @Mr.Alien - That won't work, because with `someFunc()` as currently defined `key2` is always in the object, just sometimes it has the *value* `undefined`.

Comment: @nnnnnn cool.. got it.. I thought your key might be optional

Answer (score 1):

if you need to check specifically value type then you have to use following like this.

```
if(value === false){} 
or
if(value === undefined){}
```

other that using if(false) or if(undefined) are ok.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking about is known as "Object Detection". The code needs to be built in a way to detect if the object exists & if so, then operate on that object. The preferred way of making your code bullet-proof / bug free is to do this:

```
if (obj && obj.key2){ // If object and object property both exist...
  // Do something here...
}
```

To properly use the undefined type in JavaScript with the `var` keyword (in order to avoid the unexpected conditional flipping behavior described at this SO article: [Behavior of the typeof keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635341/behavior-of-the-typeof-keyword)), you may want to prefix it with the "typeof" keyword. Then its output can be compared as a string, using the the triple equal "===" operator. Like so:

```
if (typeof value === 'undefined'){ 
  // Do something...
}
```

I tend to use these optional parenthesis, but they aren't required. It's just a coding style, which I like to read:

```
if (typeof(value) === 'undefined'){ 
  // Do something...
}
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
var obj = {};
var someFunc = function(a){
   obj = {
      "key1": true,
      "key2": a,
      "key3": !a
   };

   // True > False Example:
   if (obj && obj.key2) { // true
      // Do something true...
   } else { // false
      // Do something else...
   }

   // False > True Example, using a "not condition" AKA "!" AKA an exclamation point:
   if (obj && !obj.key3) { // false
      // Here you're checking for the object, but the false value for the key3 property.
   } else if (obj && obj.key3) { // true
      // Here you'd need the object detection again, as you'd be checking for the key3 property on that object.
   }
};
```

That's just an example, but you won't need the object detection, because you are declaring `obj` as a global & then assigning values to it in your function. Do you see why?

It's also better to put the var into the function, like so:

```
var obj = {
   "key1": true,
   "key2": a,
   "key3": !a
};
```

That removes it from the global scope & scopes it into the function block itself.

I'd also recommend learning about the "[let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)" keyword & how it can replace "var".

Something awesome, would look like this:

```
let someFunc = function(json) {
   // Another object detection example:
   if (json) {

      // Since key1 is always true, we don't need the if/else for it.
      // Just add any key1 code here, without the if(...) statement.

      // Switches are faster than if/else-if/else statements.
      switch(json.key2) {
         case true:
            // Do something true with key2...
            break;
         case false:
            // Do something else with key2...
            break;
      }

      switch(json.key3) {
         case true:
            // Do something true with key3...
            break;
         case false:
            // Do something else with key3...
            break;
      }
   }
};

// Usage:
someFunc({
  "key1": true,
  "key2": a,
  "key3": !a
});
```

Comment: *"To properly use the undefined type in JavaScript, you have to prefix it with the "typeof" keyword"* - No you don't. `variable === undefined` is fine if you know that `variable` has been declared, and `typeof variable` will give a ReferenceError if `variable` is used in the "temporal dead zone" of a variable declared with `let` or `const`.

Comment: Yes it "is fine if you know that `variable` has been declared", however code can be written without knowing if variable has been declared or not. Variables can be bypassed when overloading a method & checking for the arguments, without using any parameters. The problem - as described at the Behavior of the typeof keyword http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635341/behavior-of-the-typeof-keyword article is that sometimes the logic switches behavior unexpectedly. Checking the typeof keyword's output to see if it's a string will prevent that unexpected behavior from occurring.

Comment: But...you've even updated your answer to talk about `let`, despite the fact that the use of `typeof` that you suggest *doesn't work with `let`*. The question you linked to in your comment is irrelevant because it has nothing to do with a variable not being defined, it is about object properties not being defined. *"Checking the typeof keyword's output to see if it's a string"* - The `typeof` operator *always* returns a string (unless a reference error occurs).

Comment: Final thoughts: 1) It's cool that people are finally attempting to fix this buggy language, with the new `let` & `const` keywords. :-) 2) I recommended studying `let` as a future research subject for the OP. 3) I don't see any mixing of `let` & `typeof` in either of my code examples. 3) I was also showing the correct `typeof undefined` syntax which works with the `var` keyword & eliminates the unexpected switching of the behavioral logic. See the other SO link above. 5) I edited my answer nnnnnn. :-)

Comment: Aha! I've discovered that the `typeof` keyword does indeed work with the `const` and `let` keywords, even in strict mode! I don't see any reference errors in the console log. Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/7uwkLymc/

Comment: Yes, it does work *except* (as per my original comment) if used within the "temporal dead zone". So (as per both of my previous comments) it doesn't work to test if a `let` or `const` variable has been declared. https://jsfiddle.net/7uwkLymc/5/ (I never said it didn't work at all, I said it didn't work for "the use of `typeof` that you suggest" to test for undeclared variables.)

Answer (score 1):

**Definitions of the 'false' and 'undefined':**

If you give an `if` statement that compares false, then it is specifically looking for the **boolean** false. But, if a variable is undefined, it is automatically false anyway.

If an `if` statement looks for undefined, it is specifically looking for a **variable that has never been defined or was assigned undefined as its value**. An if statement `if (!variable)` will accept both false or undefined as the value of variable.

**So what's the bottom line?**

It makes no difference from false or undefined if and only if the if statement looks like this:

```
if (variable) {
// variable can be undefined or false
}
```

But, if the statement looks like it is below, it will only accept one of the two, depending on which it was matched with:

```
if (variable == false) {
// Now it strictly must be "false". Undefined is not accepted
}
```

Comment: `if (variable == false)` would also match if `variable` is `0` or `"0"` or `""`.

Comment: @Kaiido - `"0"` is truthy, but `"0" == false` evaluates as `true` because the `==` operator does some type coercion. (Similarly, `"0" != false` evaluates as `false`.) Using `===` instead of `==` avoids this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on scenario that how do you check the value, in my opinion.

- If you want to check any value exist
  You just need `if(obj.key2)`
- If you want to check value does not exist, opposite of previous condition, just like  `if(!obj.key2)`
- If you want to check specific type, you would have used type check with `===`
  either `if(obj.key2 === undefined)` or `if(obj['key2'] === undefined)`
- Else you can set default value as false. `key2: a || false`, Also ES6 has given nice feature for assigning default value into parameter. `function(a = false){ }`
- Hope this will make your clear.